# typo while installing wine

Tags: command-line, sudo, repository

I was trying to install `wine` on my desktop install of 18.04 bionic and the website was formatted in a way I couldn’t highlight the commands so I started typing them on my tiny keyboard, with no backlight, and as a goon, I typed a typo, with the website `dl.winehq.prg` vs. `org`.  Well I exited the terminal (all terminals in fact) and put the web page into reader view and was able to copy the commands flawlessly, but when I try to run it again, typed correctly, it tries to access that website at `.prg` again, what do I do?

[image: my error screen]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to remove the erroneous repository using `apt-add-repository --remove`

So

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove https://dl.winehq.prg/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```